# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: laravel, put

> I have the following code in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $cook = cooks::findOrFail($id);

    if (!$cook) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Sorry, cook with id ' . $id . ' cannot be found',
        ], 400);
    }

    $updated = $cook->fill($request->all())
        ->save();

    if ($updated) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Sorry, cook could not be updated',
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

> And when I use in my postman method PUT I received this message "The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST."
>
> > in my api.php I have the following line:
>
> Route::resource('cook', 'cookList');
>
> > and here is the route that I use in postman:

```
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cook`
```

> with body id-1 and title-cook
>   Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What url did you use to execute the `PUT` request? `/api/cook/1`? And you should fix the `cooks::findOrFail` to `Cook::findOrFail`

Comment: Please provide the code that you calling your route.

Comment: sorry for that, I updated my article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a parameter in your route. As you are using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cook` it's guessing you are trying to go to the `index` method or `store` method. So add a id parameter to your route and it should work with `PUT` method.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cook/1`

(Not tested, but should work)

Comment: ahh, sorry for such a dumb question.
yes, you are right, Thanks man

Comment: I am trying to send parameters with the body from the postman but they cann't receive it.
they receive only if I put like this "/api/cook/1?title=alone"

Comment: check out this link: https://laravel-nepal.com/laravel-api-put-patch-not-sending-parameters-postman/

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Form Method Spoofing:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing

[image]